# devise 'reset password' not saving new password but lets you sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, passwords

So devise's 'reset password' used to work in my application but now it's breaking. I'm on rails 4.1.0, devise 3.2.4. Here's what's happening:

1) user clicks forgot password, enters in their email, receives change password link in email, clicks and is correctly sent to the change password page, enters in a new password, and gets signed in.

2) BUT if they log out, they are unable to sign in with the new password.

In console looks like the encrypted password does change after you change password. But it's not updating with the correct password.

FYI I have custom 'new' and 'create' actions in user registrations. Otherwise here's what I have in the User model for devise:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

Here's my change password form...

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <% if notice %>
    <div class="alert-info alert">
      <p><%= notice %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% if alert %>
    <div class="alert-danger alert">
      <p><%= alert %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :password, "New password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, :autofocus => true, :class=>'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group'>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class=>'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class='form-group center formSubmit'>
    <%= f.submit "Change my password", :class=>'btn btn-large btn-primary'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And finally, here's my routes for devise:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
  as :user do
    post "/users/sign_up" => "registrations#create", :as => :v2_user_registration
  end
```

Really weird problem, right?

UPDATE:

Here's application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  include Pundit
  include SessionsHelper

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :set_user

  rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized

  private 

    def auth_user
      if params[:special]
        user = User.find_by_special(params[:special])
        if user
          sign_in user
          redirect_to '/files'
        end
        authenticate_user!
      else
        authenticate_user!
      end
    end
   def set_user
       Gon.global.user = current_user
   end
end
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of ApplicationController in the question.

Comment: Sure. Added ApplicationController to question.

Comment: did you every figure this out? Ihave the same problem. :( @user2004922

Comment: no...never figured this out.